# Parson JSON Object from QR Code after being scanned

Tags: android, json, qr-code

In my qr code i have this JSON Object :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("name", editTextName.getText().toString());
        json.put("price", editTextPrice.getText().toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BarcodeQRCode barcodeQRCode = new BarcodeQRCode(json.toString(), 1000, 1000, null);
    Image codeQrImage = barcodeQRCode.getImage();
    codeQrImage.scaleAbsolute(100, 80);
    document.add(codeQrImage);
```

But when i try to parse it,

```
//this is the qr code context after scanned, i just declared it for clarifications
  String scannedQrCode = "\"name\":\"Nissan Urvan Original 12v\",\"price\":\"2500\"}";
 try {
                    mainObject = new JSONObject(scannedQrCode);
                    String nameItem = (String) mainObject.get( "name" );
                    String priceItem = (String) mainObject.get( "price" );
                    Log.e("TESTING",""+nameItem +priceItem);
                } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
                    jsonException.printStackTrace();
                }
```

it says in the logcat that :

> org.json.JSONException: Value name of type java.lang.String cannot be
> converted to JSONObject

is there a problem with my json object? is it on the creation?

Answer (score 1):

Add starting `{` in `"\"name\":\"Nissan Urvan Original 12v\",\"price\":\"2500\"}"`:

```
"{\"name\":\"Nissan Urvan Original 12v\",\"price\":\"2500\"}"
```